# Republishing a SQL Server CLR assembly using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sqlclr

I created a CLR assembly with several utility functions and published it to SQL Server 2012 using Visual Studio 2015.  Everything worked.

I wanted to change the input parameter for a particular function from `int?` to `long?`.  I made that change, rebuilt the project and republished it, but the changed CLR assembly was not replaced.

I tried dropping the function from T-SQL:

```
drop function myFunc
```

and it was successfully dropped from the database. Then I republished again from Visual Studio, but now the function is simply gone from the database. It was not replaced by the republish.

I tried dropping the assembly but the drop failed with the error that 'myAssemblyName' was referenced by object 'foo', one of the functions in the assembly.

Is there a built-in feature in Visual Studio that handles the necessary housekeeping tasks on the server when making selective updates to individual items in an assembly? Do these steps have to be done "manually" in T-SQL outside of Visual Studio?

Edit:

I looked at the install script and the section where work was done was blank. I don't know why. So I changed the project from `Any CPU` to `x64` and rebuilt and republished, and then everything was working again.

```
<snip>
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you published to the instance and database that you are checking? The dropping of the function and assembly are handled automatically by the publish process. Also, don't use those datatypes for SQLCLR. Use `SqlInt32` or `SqlInt64`.

Comment: Yes, I am certain that the right database was being pointed to. I looked at the script and it wasn't doing anything! The work section of the script was blank  For some reason, VS thought there was nothing to be done.  So I changed the project from `Any CPU` to `64 bit` and rebuilt and republished, and it worked. I will add that info to my question.

Comment: Architecture shouldn't have anything to do with it. If it did make a difference then you might have made a change in the configuration manager. Go to the configuration manager and make sure that the project is set to Any CPU and that both Build and Deployment options are checked. Then try again to "Publish Solution".

Comment: @srutzky: I don't know what tests VS does to see if there's anything to be published (has the assembly changed?) but surely a change of target CPU should trigger that section of the script to do something and have content, and that's why I made that specific change. The problem is that the script was blank in that part. There was nothing after `USE [$(DatabaseName)];` After change of CPU, there was something there.

Comment: So then put it back to Any CPU and see if it still publishes. Changing the datatype, even to an inappropriate one, would have been enough to cause a regeneration of the Assembly and publish it.

Comment: @srutzky: Yes, any change to the CPU (from "any" to x64 or from x64 to "any") causes the publish to succeed.  It is a mystery to me why the first one did not succeed, when all that was changed was the data type of a parameter of one of the several functions in the assembly. I honestly can't say why the script was blank in that section. And shouldn't you be able to republish a CLR assembly which is unchanged in any way, say if something got deleted accidentally on the server?

Comment: SSDT publish process is incremental only. The script is generated based on current state of target Database. There is an option check for "create script" that will generate full drop and recreate script.

Comment: @srutzky: Is the state of the assembly in the target database compared to the state of the to-be-published assembly? Are the ancillary items, like the SQL functions that invoke the assembly code, also checked?

Comment: Yes, I _believe_ that everything is checked, but you would have to confirm via SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see what exactly is being checked. If you put it back to Any CPU and publish, does it actually publish? Then if you change the datatype to `SqlInt64` and publish, does it actually publish?

Comment: In SSMS, on the Assembly properties pane, the DateCreated changes, so I assume it has been published. I will have to run some further tests if that isn't enough to go by, such as changing the datatype on another function and testing afterwards in T-SQL.

Comment: Yes, if `DateCreated` is newer then it has been published. You need to put everything back the way it was in the beginning (i.e. `Any CPU` and `int?`) and republish. Assuming that works, do that first change from `int?` to `long?` (or better yet, to `SqlInt64`) and try to re-publish. We need to be able to reproduce the original issue before proceeding as it could have been some edge case / stale file, etc.